# NestedScrollView scroll lags until CollapsingToolbarLayout view does not collapse

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, nestedscrollview

Hi I am experincing a kind of lag when NestedScrollView is scrolled and this scroll lag is observed until view does collapse once view is collapsed scroll is working fine.

Is there any solution not this.

Following is xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <com.antonioleiva.materializeyourapp.widgets.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/FabStyle"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use [this](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout) library. I think it will solve your problem.

For sake of completeness, I am posting the code taken from the above libraries' example

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/smooth_app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_arrow_back"
        style="@style/AppStyle.MdToolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </me.henrytao.smoothappbarlayout.SmoothAppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```